# operator<< overload. Unable to directly use the result of another overloaded operator directly in cout

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am making a Complex number class in order to work on overloading operators.

```
#include <iostream>
class Complex
{
    double real;
    double imaginary;

public:

    Complex(double real, double imaginary) : real(real), imaginary(imaginary) {}
    ~Complex() = default;

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, Complex &source)
    {
        out << "(" << source.real << " + " << source.imaginary << ")";
        return out;
    }

    friend Complex operator+(const Complex &a, const Complex &b)
    {
        return Complex(a.real + b.real, a.imaginary + b.imaginary);
    }

};

int main()
{
    Complex c1(3, 2.25);
    Complex c2(2.25, 3);
    Complex res = c1 + c2;

    std::cout << res;
    return 0;
}
```

The class definition is not finished as I need to overload a few operators more. However if I compile and run the project I get the result printed on my screen as expected though if I don't use a result variable in order to print for cout `cout<< c1+c2;`I am getting the following error:

```
error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' and 'cmp::Complex')
```

If I try to use `cout<< &(c1+c2);` I get the error message:

```
error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]
```

and it was not my intention to have to write it like that.

I am under the impression that it fails because c1+c2 is not taken as a reference since it is a temporary object that is not saved anywhere and since I cannot take a reference of a temporary object according to the second error, it fails. This explains why when I save the result of c1+c2 on result I can execute the program without errors.

In the video I was watching, Eclipse was used and in my case I am using Codeblocks with GNU GCC compiler.

Could you help me understand what am I doing wrong ? Why isn't it working in my case but works with the same syntax on the video ?

EDIT:
Solution: The << operator function should be taking a const reference of Complex type instead. A temporary object can only be bound to a const reference.Thus the prototype of it should look something like this...

```
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out,const Complex &source);
```

Comment: Look for examples on web and play spot the difference.

Comment: References to non-constant object can not bind to temporary objects or [*prvalues*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#prvalue). You need a `const` reference.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It was the solution alas I didn't understand it at the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`c1+c2` produces a temporary object, this can't be bound to the non-const reference in your stream operator. You need to change it to a const reference

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem:

```
...
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out,Complex &source);
...
cout<< c1+c2; // error or warning
...
```

#### Why isn't it working?

Expression  of `c1+c2`evaluates to temporary object of [prvalue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#prvalue).

`std::cout<<c1+c2;` is trying to bind prvalue to lvalue reference

> All temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the
>   full-expression that (lexically) contains the point where they were
>   created, and if multiple temporary objects were created, they are
>   destroyed in the order opposite to the order of creation. This is true
>   even if that evaluation ends in throwing an exception.

#### Solution?

> The lifetime of a temporary object may be extended by binding to a
>   const lvalue reference or to an rvalue reference (since C++11)

```
...
//  using rvalue reference
friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, Complex &&source)
{
    source.real += 100; // non const value in function signature allows us to modify 'source'
    out << "(" << source.real << " + " << source.imaginary << ")";
    return out;
}
...
```

Adding `const` qualifier to the function argument:

```
...
// using const lvalue reference
friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Complex &source)
{
    out << "(" << source.real << " + " << source.imaginary << ")";
    return out;
}
...
```

#### What if we have all of this overloads at the same time?

> When used as a function argument and when two overloads of the
>   function are available, one taking rvalue reference parameter and the
>   other taking lvalue reference to const parameter, an rvalue binds to
>   the rvalue reference overload (thus, if both copy and move
>   constructors are available, an rvalue argument invokes the move
>   constructor, and likewise with copy and move assignment operators).

#### Example:

```
#include ...

int main()
{
    Complex c1(3, 2.25);
    Complex c2(2.25, 3);

    auto lvalue = c1 + c2;
    auto && rlvalueRef = c1 + c2;
    const auto& constlvalueRef = c1 + c2;
    const auto constlvalue = c1 + c2;

    std::cout
        << constlvalue
        << lvalue
        << rlvalueRef
        << constlvalueRef
        << c1 + c2
        << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

#### Output:

```
non modified: (5.25 + 5.25)
non modified: (5.25 + 5.25)
non modified: (5.25 + 5.25)
non modified: (5.25 + 5.25)
modified output: (105.25 + 5.25)
```

Comment: Why are you even suggesting the rvalue reference overload? It's obvious that's not what the OP wants, or what a stream insertion operator should ever take, and your answer doesn't make it clear at all that it is unnecessary.

Comment: @SebastianRedl, I can't say what OP exactly wants. The problem is much deeper than it seems. The general problem is binding rvalue to lvalue reference. And i didn't find enough information about it even in ISO/IEC 14882:2017. Why `c1+c2` compiles in MSCV, and why other compilers refuse to compile it?

Comment: Because MSVC had the ill-advised "non-const lvalue references can bind to prvalues" extension since just about forever.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate explanation. While I will stick to the lvalue reference it is nice knowing that I can do it another way as well. Even If I would probably never write it that way it might help me identify what is going on, when reading someone else's code.

Comment: @Madryoch, this was the real reason why I posted the solution using rvalue reference, despite the fact that is bad practice to use it with overloading ostream operator <<